# Possible null pointer dereference in com. <package> . NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE

Tags: java, maven

I am having below code base.

```
 private void buildHiveConfAndVars(final StringBuilder hiveConfbuilder, final StringBuilder hiveVarBuilder)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(variableDirectories)) {
        return;
    }
    String[] hiveVariableDirectoryPaths = variableDirectories.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < hiveVariableDirectoryPaths.length; i++) {
        File hiveVariableDirectory = new File(hiveVariableDirectoryPaths[i]);
        File[] hiveVariableFiles = hiveVariableDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(final File file) {
                return file.getName().endsWith(variableFileExtension);
            }
        });
        for (int j = 0; j < hiveVariableFiles.length; j++) {
            buildVariableMapFromFile(hiveVarBuilder, hiveVariableFiles[j].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(variableFiles)) {
        return;
    }
    String[] hiveVariableFilePaths = variableFiles.split(",");
    buildVariableMap(hiveVarBuilder, hiveVariableFilePaths);
}
```

I am running findbugs-maven-plugin on it. So getting below warning.

```
[INFO] Possible null pointer dereference in com.<package-name>.PigUnitMojo.buildHiveConfAndVars(StringBuilder, StringBuilder) due to return value of called method [com.<package-name>.PigUnitMojo, com.<package-name>.PigUnitMojo] Dereferenced at PigUnitMojo.java:[line 441]Known null at PigUnitMojo.java:[line 433] NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE
```

[INFO] Possible null pointer dereference in com..PigUnitMojo.buildHiveConfAndVars(StringBuilder, StringBuilder) due to return value of called method [com..PigUnitMojo, com..PigUnitMojo] Dereferenced at PigUnitMojo.java:[line 441]Known null at PigUnitMojo.java:[line 433] NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at these lines:

```
File[] hiveVariableFiles = hiveVariableDirectory.listFiles(...)
for (int j = 0; j < hiveVariableFiles.length; j++) {
```

... because `listFiles` will return `null` if no files are found. So remember to check for nulls on every value returned by `File.listFiles`.